# Ignoring Autocorrect on Pages?

Tags: pages, autocorrect

On Pages, how do I ignore an autocorrect suggestion? I use the esc key to ignore the suggestion, but as soon as I press space bar it changes the word anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Open Pages as usual then go to the **Edit** menu:

Scroll down to **Spelling and Grammar** submenu and disable **Correct Spelling Automatically**.

Additionally you can disable **Check Spelling While Typing**.